# Можно ли переименовать файл перед отправкой на сервер а потом в папку PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

хотел бы узнать есть ли у php функция которая перед отправкой файла на сервер переименует его? Хочу сделать чтобы пользователь загрузив свой файл перед отправкой он переименовался в свой порядочный номер. Например, в папке находится файл с номером 26, а я хочу чтобы файл, который будет загружаться с последующим увеличивался на один. И на выходе чтобы получалось что в папке появлялись файлы с порядочным номером 27, 28 и тд. Это осуществима ?

Вот сам код:

```
<form action="download.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" style=" width: 302px; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 40px; margin-bottom: auto;">
<em class="mb">Файлы не более 35mb!</em>
<input class="n4" type="file" name="filename" style="color: #fff;"><br>
<input class="n4" type="submit" value="Отправить" style="margin-top: 15px;">
<div class="message">
<?php
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'], 'topone/'.$_FILES['filename']['name'])){
    if($_FILES['filename']['size'] > 2*1024*1024){
        exit('<p style="color:#FF0000">Размер файла привышает 35mb !</p>');
    }else{
    echo '<p style="color:#00FF00"> Всё КРУТО !!!</p><br>';
    echo 'Характеристики вашего файла:<br>';
    echo 'Имя файла: ';
    echo $_FILES['filename']['name'] .'<br>';
    echo 'Размер: ';
    echo $_FILES['filename']['size'] .' kb<br>';
    echo 'Тип файла: ';
    echo $_FILES['filename']['type'] .'<br>';
    } 
        }
?>
</div>  
</form>
```

Comment: второй параметр [move_uploaded_file](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

Answer (score 0):

Запросы обрабатываются параллельно, и есть небольшая вероятность наложения.

Лучше считать хэш (например md5) от содержимого и использовать как имя (второй параметр move_uploaded_file).

Как бонус, файлы не будут храниться дважды.

Дополнительную информацию о файле можно сохранять в базу данных.